# TSynSpellCheck - подскажите альтернативу для Delphi

Tags: delphi

Нужно добавить проверку орфографии в приложение на Delphi. За основу взял [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/). В примерах используется для подчеркивания неправильных слов компонент TSynSpellCheck, но, к сожалению, самого компонента с примерами нет, да и скачать его нельзя - сайт http://www.synspellcheck.prv.pl/ не доступен. 
Помогите найти альтернативу этому компоненту или может у кого завалался...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут вроде есть
http://sourceforge.net/projects/synedit/files/

Comment: Этот по-моему подсвечивает синтаксис, а мне надо, чтобы волнистой подчеркивал как в Word

Comment: Не уверен но этот компонет тоже вроде там должен быть принцип тотже самый